# Radio button selected value is not retained in the Stack Exchange network profile reputation tab

Tags: bug, design, stackexchange.com, network-profile, reputation-graph

In the [Stack Exchange network profile reputation tab](https://stackexchange.com/users/current/?tab=reputation), there are two options available to show the communities reputations.

- Top 5 accounts
- All accounts

When switching the options in the radio buttons the filter is working but the selected value is not retained in the radio button.

**GIF for the same:**

[image: Stack Exchange Reputation tab - Radio buttons]

**Update:**
Instead of single click, if we double clicked the radio button, it retaining the selection.

Comment: And the problem still persists, after 6 years ...